# Aggregations with conditions using `any` in R data.table on a large dataset are slow

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large dataset (> 300 mio. rows) with the following columns:

- `ID` (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
- `groupA` (A, B, C, ...)
- `groupB` (X, Y, Z, ...)
- `value` (numeric)
- `remark` ("", "type1", "type2", "type3", ...)

I want to group by groupA and groupB, and get the following information: mean of `value`, and know if any of the `remark` properties is true for any row of this specific groupA-groupB combination.

In general, this works with the following code:

```R
DT[, .(
    mean_value = mean(value), 
    any_type1 = any(remark == "type1"), 
    any_type2 = any(remark == "type2"), 
    any_type3 = any(remark == "type3")
), by = .(groupA, groupB)]
```

However, it appears that this does not run efficiently:

- For a sample of 1 Mio. rows it finishes in around 4sec.
- For a sample of 10 Mio. rows it finishes in around 42sec.

For my entire data set it would take a considerable amount of time, which I would like to avoid, as this should be performed multiple times.

Any other aggreation works smoothly on the entire data (< 30sec), including modifying values using `:=`.

Does anyone know if and why using data.table in combination with `any` is particularly unefficient? Has anyone a possible solution or workaround?

It would be much faster to add extra fields with filters and group by these to get to the same results, but this would add many code, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you reverse it using `%in%`, as in `any_type1 = "type1" %in% remark`?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It has exactly the same speed :-/

Comment: (I just tried it with 10Mi rows and using `%in%` is around 20-30% faster than `any(==)`. It must be a data-structure thing, mine is rather naive and based solely on some random sampling from your description.)

Comment: @gabolo, can you provide realistic toy data? There are probably ways to safe time but hard to tell which would work without a more concrete idea of what the data looks like.